# Jquery how to count checked and disable checkboxes

Tags: jquery

I am trying to disable all unchecked checkboxes when there are 5 checked checkboxes.

My code is not working here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/mtYtW/18/

My Jquery:

```
var countchecked = $('table input[type="checkbox"]').find(":checked").length

    if(countcheckhed > 5) {
        $("table input:checkbox").attr("disabled", true);
    } else {}
```

My HTML:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="770px;">
  <tbody><tr style="border: 1px solid green; height: 40px; font-size: 14px;">
    <th>Feature 1</th>
    <th>Feature 2</th>
    <th>Feuture 3</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="checkit"><input type="hidden" value="0" name="search[windows_is_true]"><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="search[windows_is_true]" id="search_windows_is_true"></td>
    <td>Test 1</td>
    <td>Test 2</td>
    <td>Test 3</td>
    <td>Test 4</td>
    <td>Test 5</td>
    <td>Test 6</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="checkit"><input type="hidden" value="0" name="search[windows_is_true]"><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="search[windows_is_true]" id="search_windows_is_true"></td>
    <td>Test 1</td>
    <td>Test 2</td>
    <td>Test 3</td>
    <td>Test 4</td>
    <td>Test 5</td>
    <td>Test 6</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="checkit"><input type="hidden" value="0" name="search[windows_is_true]"><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="search[windows_is_true]" id="search_windows_is_true"></td>
    <td>Test 1</td>
    <td>Test 2</td>
    <td>Test 3</td>
    <td>Test 4</td>
    <td>Test 5</td>
    <td>Test 6</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="checkit"><input type="hidden" value="0" name="search[windows_is_true]"><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="search[windows_is_true]" id="search_windows_is_true"></td>
    <td>Test 1</td>
    <td>Test 2</td>
    <td>Test 3</td>
    <td>Test 4</td>
    <td>Test 5</td>
    <td>Test 6</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="checkit"><input type="hidden" value="0" name="search[windows_is_true]"><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="search[windows_is_true]" id="search_windows_is_true"></td>
    <td>Test 1</td>
    <td>Test 2</td>
    <td>Test 3</td>
    <td>Test 4</td>
    <td>Test 5</td>
    <td>Test 6</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="checkit"><input type="hidden" value="0" name="search[windows_is_true]"><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="search[windows_is_true]" id="search_windows_is_true"></td>
    <td>Test 1</td>
    <td>Test 2</td>
    <td>Test 3</td>
    <td>Test 4</td>
    <td>Test 5</td>
    <td>Test 6</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="checkit"><input type="hidden" value="0" name="search[windows_is_true]"><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="search[windows_is_true]" id="search_windows_is_true"></td>
    <td>Test 1</td>
    <td>Test 2</td>
    <td>Test 3</td>
    <td>Test 4</td>
    <td>Test 5</td>
    <td>Test 6</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="checkit"><input type="hidden" value="0" name="search[windows_is_true]"><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="search[windows_is_true]" id="search_windows_is_true"></td>
    <td>Test 1</td>
    <td>Test 2</td>
    <td>Test 3</td>
    <td>Test 4</td>
    <td>Test 5</td>
    <td>Test 6</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="checkit"><input type="hidden" value="0" name="search[windows_is_true]"><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="search[windows_is_true]" id="search_windows_is_true"></td>
    <td>Test 1</td>
    <td>Test 2</td>
    <td>Test 3</td>
    <td>Test 4</td>
    <td>Test 5</td>
    <td>Test 6</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="checkit"><input type="hidden" value="0" name="search[windows_is_true]"><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="search[windows_is_true]" id="search_windows_is_true"></td>
    <td>Test 1</td>
    <td>Test 2</td>
    <td>Test 3</td>
    <td>Test 4</td>
    <td>Test 5</td>
    <td>Test 6</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="checkit"><input type="hidden" value="0" name="search[windows_is_true]"><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="search[windows_is_true]" id="search_windows_is_true"></td>
    <td>Test 1</td>
    <td>Test 2</td>
    <td>Test 3</td>
    <td>Test 4</td>
    <td>Test 5</td>
    <td>Test 6</td>
  </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Comment: Please add your code to the question as well.  For the future if jsfiddle ever disappears the question will still be relevant.

Comment: The js fiddle you supplied simply passes the code onload and then never checks again.  Try getting all of the checkboxes and adding a .click attribute and re-evaluating the check count.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The following should do the trick for your needs:**

```
$("table input[type=checkbox]").click(function(){
var countchecked = $("table input[type=checkbox]:checked").length;

if(countchecked >= 5) 
{
    $('table input[type=checkbox]').not(':checked').attr("disabled",true);
}
else
{
    $('table input[type=checkbox]').not(':checked').attr("disabled",false);
}
```

});

[Example for your needs](http://jsfiddle.net/mtYtW/51/)

**(Generic) The following will disable all of your unchecked checkboxes:**

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').not(':checked').attr("disabled","disabled");
```

[Generic Disable Example](http://jsfiddle.net/mtYtW/35/)

Comment: How to enable all the checkboxes when one of the 6 checkboxes are unchecked?

Comment: The else statement handles that :) You can check the first example

Comment: Thanks very much! Perfect example.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('table input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
    var countcheck = $('table input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;
    if(countcheck > 4) {
        $("table input:checkbox:not(:checked)").attr("disabled", true);
    }else
    {
        $("table input:checkbox").attr("disabled", false);
    }
});
```

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/mtYtW/48/

**NOTE: This code will enable the checkboxes if you deselect one of the five!**

Comment: No it wont. It will allow 6 checkboxes to be selected.

Answer (score 1):

Your code was close, with a few major issues.

http://jsfiddle.net/mtYtW/37/

```
$(function() {
    $('table input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
        var countchecked = $('table input[type="checkbox"]').filter(":checked").length

        if (countchecked >= 5) {
            $("table input:checkbox").not(":checked").attr("disabled", true);
        }else{
            $("table input:checkbox").attr("disabled", false);
        }
    });
});
```

The biggest, you had your code only executing onload.  You need to execute it any time one of the checkboxes is checked, that is this part:

```
$('table input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
```

You had a misspelled variable name `countcheck` did not exist, it was `countchecked`.

You were using `find` when you really wanted `filter`.  Find will search in the descendants of the elements in your set, you wanted to filter them.

You had `> 5` when you stated you wanted to disable AT 5.  So it should be `>=`.

You were disabling ALL checkboxes, not just the unchecked as you stated, I added `.not(":checked")`.

And finally, I figured you would probably want to re-enable them if one was unchecked, so I added:

```
}else{
    $("table input:checkbox").attr("disabled", false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to disable the rest of the check boxes once the checked checkboxes count gets more than 5.If that is the case try this:

```
$('table input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
    var countchecked = $('table input[type="checkbox"]').filter(":checked").length;

    if(countchecked > 4) {
        $("table input:checkbox").not(":checked").attr("disabled", true);
    } else {}
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/mtYtW/30/

If you want to disable the checkboxes on the page load and verify if there are more than 5 checkboxes that are checked then try this:

```
$(function(){
    var countchecked = $('table input[type="checkbox"]').filter(":checked").length;

    if(countchecked > 4) {
        $("table input:checkbox").not(":checked").attr("disabled", true);
    } else {}
});
```

Comment: The "> 5" part will allow selecting 6 checkboxes.

Comment: @holodoc: Missed the 'when there are 5 checked checkboxes' part of the question and went by the condition used the OP's original Code. Fixed it

Comment: LOL its funny to watch people how they all changed their solutions after this remark :D

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this

http://jsfiddle.net/mtYtW/33/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(':checkbox').bind('click', function(){
    if($(':checkbox:checked').length >= 5) {
        $(':checkbox').not(':checked').prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
        $(':checkbox').not(':checked').prop('disabled', false);
    }
});
```

Note that `prop` is jQuery 1.6 exclusive. In case of jQuery < 1.6 use `attr`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("table input[type=checkbox]").click(function(){
    var countchecked = $("table input[type=checkbox]:checked").length;
    if(countchecked >= 5) {
        $("table input:checkbox").attr("disabled", true);
    }else{

    }
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Re5uy/6/