# Counting checked checkboxes

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I'm having a problem counting checked checkboxes in jQuery that runs counter to every example I could find. The following code works:

```
var checked_boxes = $('input:checkbox:checked').length // Returns 1 or 2 etc.
```

However, I would like to modify that to count the number of checkboxes of a particular class, say `my_class`. I have tried the following:

```
var checked_boxes = $('input.my_class:checked').length // Always 0
var checked_boxes = $('input.my_class:checkbox:checked').length // Always 0
var checked_boxes = $('input[type=checkbox].my_class:checked').length // 0 also
```

Same with several other syntaxes/permutations I tried.

For some background, these checkboxes are in a table in a td and essentially look like so:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cb1" class="some_class_for_display_style my_class" value="1" />Blah
```

Any idea what I'm missing here?

EDIT:

Found the problem: It was the mis-placed class. I added an answer to that effect.

Comment: might it be the dollar sign before input? `$('$input')`

Comment: Rats.. typo.. fixed.. apologize!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fastest [Rubber Duck](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/03/rubber-duck-problem-solving.html) answer ever!!

Right after posting here I went back to looking at my code and realized to my horror that I had applied the class to the td not the `check_box_tag` (I'm using Rails).. moved the class to the `check_box_tag` and it seems to be working now.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 18):

Remove the $ sign in the selector.

`$('input.my_class:checked').length` - Count of checkboxes which are checked

`$('input.my_class').length` - Count of all checkboxes with class my_class

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for:

It will be good if you can provide a working JSFiddle but hope link below will help you.

Example: (You are looking mix of these 2)

http://jsfiddle.net/mtYtW/30/
AND
http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/LUtJF/1/

Few good answers here:

[Jquery how to count checked and disable checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6960921/jquery-how-to-count-checked-and-disable-checkboxes)

Hope it helps, Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If `$input` is a PHP variable, you need to escape the JS string to use the variable:

```
var checked_boxes = $('<?php echo $input ?>'.my_class:checked).length;
```

If it is a JS variable, same thing:

```
var checked_boxes = $('input.<?php echo $my_class; ?>:checked').length;
```

And if it is not a variable, you just need to remove the initial `$` from the selector:

```
var checked_boxes = $('input.my_class:checked').length;
```